# EF Seed ignoring the DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, migration

I have a problem with the attribute `DatabaseGenerate(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)`, it seems to be the case that it is not respected by the `AddOrUpdate()` call within the Seed method.

I have made a simple project, to illustrate my issue:

```
public class EFModel : DbContext
{
    public EFModel()
        : base("name=EFModel")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string DefaultName { get; set; }

}
```

The Seed call

```
protected override void Seed(DummyEF.EFModel context)
{
    context.MyEntities.AddOrUpdate(new MyEntity { Id = 10, Name = "Samual", DefaultName = "Sam" });

    context.MyEntities.AddOrUpdate(new MyEntity { Id = 11, Name = "David" });

}
```

When I run the `Update-Database` command, with the first Seed row (`that is with Samual, and specifying a value for the default name`) it works fine. When I run it with the second line (that is with Dadid, and without specifying a value for the DefaultName) it fails:

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See
>   'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

The table it self is valid, and has a default constraint, so normal insert into via SQL works.

> It just seems to be the case, that the Seed is ignoring the fact that
>   the entity property is marked with the
>   DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed attribute.

Any idea why this is ignored?

I am using EF 6 code first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion must be that the current version of EF 6 does not cater for the combination of the attriburtes Required and DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)

So if one wants to set a column to not be nullable, yet avoid EF from validating it before the save to the database, one cannot use the Required attribute.

I guess that the Fluent API or modification of the migration code needs to be used in stead.

Answer (score 1):

When you use DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed you are telling EF not to add or update the information in the database because the database will generate it as is common for timestamps or computed SQL columns, so it makes no sense to try and seed that column. You are getting the validation error because you have it marked required.

Comment: If I remove the Required, then it will not be set to NOT NULL, and what Im trying to achieve here is a column that is not nullable, and have a default value, so that SQL Server will use the default value when it is null.

This is how EF is ment to work

And you are right that it make no sense to seed this column, that is the problem I am having, that if I do not give that property a value in the new MyEntity call, then it failes on validation.

Comment: Have you tried it with the normal Add() ? If (!context.MyEntities.Any(x => x.Id == 10)) context.MyEntities.Add(new MyEntity { Id = 11, Name = "David" });

Comment: Hi Steve,
The result is the same. and you meant to say 
If (!context.MyEntities.Any(x => x.Id == 11)) context.MyEntities.Add(new MyEntity { Id = 11, Name = "David" });

Comment: Yeah that was a typo. Odd, I have something similar with a default created date from the database and EF just ignores it for inserts and updates. I don't have it flagged required though (don't care if NULLs get in there). Is that what the validation error shows?